# extremely sluggish dell Inspiron 7000 laptop

Tags: dell-inspiron, dell

I have an extremely sluggish dell Inspiron 7000 (Dell Inspiron 7000 8GB 256SSD /Inspiron 7386 2-in-1) laptop, purchased in 2018. I have read that the RAM cannot be upgraded on this model. Is there anything that can be done to improve performance on this model or is it a throw-away job?

Comment: Run `chkdsk` and also check the SMART attributes of the disk (post them in your post if you need advice).

Comment: Back up, do a fresh install of Windows, update and check speed. If OK, add Apps slowly and check.

Comment: It depends on the *operating system*. Newer versions of Windows have become more demanding of resources. Try running from another OS on USB, such as Live Ubuntu, and see if there is a significant speed increase in daily use, such as creating a document (LibreOffice is included), web browsing, etc. No need to install, just put the OS on the USB. If it works better for you, *then* install it.

Comment: As no OS is stated assuming Windows; which turns very sluggish if there is any problem with the system disk; either it being near full or having a problem (chkdsk or smart as harrymc suggests)

Answer (score 0):

So I went for the fresh Windows install - no files kept, etc. Laptop now seems much better (but not perfect - I guess Dell didn't do a great job with this model making it non-upgradeable on the memory**).